# Plesk, forbidden 403 al cargar css y js (nginx)

Tags: codeigniter, nginx, plesk

Tengo un servidor con PLESK montado, en el que tengo un subdominio app.mysite.com creado y funcionando con nginx. 
En este subdominio, he subido mi web que está desarrollada en codeigniter.

Esta es la estructura de el proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando intento cargar mis estilos o intento acceder por url a los css (app.mysite.com/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css), me da error forbidden 403:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son las "additional directives for HTTP":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y estas para HTTPS:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El subdominio, redirige automaticamente de HTTP a HTTPS.

Para finalizar, cuando añado al final de la configuraciónd he PLESK, este código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al entrar en app.mysite.com, directamente me salta el error forbidden 403 sin ni siquiera cargar el index.php. Pero si añado este código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me carga el index.php de codeigniter pero cuando intento cargar los estilos y js, en vez de forbidden 403, me sale un error 404:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por que codeigniter está intentando carga la ruta de esta manera controller/function/...

No se como solucionar este problema, no se si puedo hacer que cuando la url sea css/ que no intente cargar ningún controlador o cambiar alguna cosa en nginx...

Para finalizar aquí dejo mi configuración de nginx:

```
    #ATTENTION!
    #
    #DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
    #SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.

    server {
            listen 206.189.5.184:443 ssl http2;

            server_name app.mysite.com;
            server_name www.app.mysite.com;
            server_name ipv4.app.mysite.com;

            ssl_certificate             /opt/psa/var/certificates/scfMQnEev;
            ssl_certificate_key         /opt/psa/var/certificates/scfMQnEev;
            ssl_client_certificate      /opt/psa/var/certificates/scfcJsJQ3;

            client_max_body_size 128m;

            root "/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/app.mysite.com";
            access_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/app.mysite.com/logs/proxy_access_ssl_log";
            error_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/app.mysite.com/logs/proxy_error_log";

            location / {
                    proxy_pass https://206.189.5.184:7081;
                    proxy_set_header Host             $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    access_log off;

            }

            location ~ ^/(plesk-stat|awstats-icon|webstat|webstat-ssl|ftpstat|anon_ftpstat) {
                    proxy_pass https://206.189.5.184:7081;
                    proxy_set_header Host             $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    access_log off;

            }
            location @fallback {
                    proxy_pass https://206.189.5.184:7081;
                    proxy_set_header Host             $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    access_log off;

            }

            location ~ ^/(.*\.(ac3|avi|bmp|bz2|css|cue|dat|doc|docx|dts|eot|exe|flv|gif|gz|htm|html|ico|img|iso|jpeg|jpg|js|mkv|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|ogg|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|qt|ra$
                    try_files $uri @fallback;
            }

            location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
                    alias /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/web_users/$1/$2;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
                    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                    fastcgi_pass "unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/app.mysite.com/php-fpm.sock";
                    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

            }

            location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
                    proxy_pass https://206.189.5.184:7081;
                    proxy_set_header Host             $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    access_log off;

            }

            location ~ \.php(/.*)?$ {
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
                    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                    fastcgi_pass "unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/app.mysite.com/php-fpm.sock";
                    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

            }
            location ~ /$ {
                    index "index.html" "index.cgi" "index.pl" "index.php" "index.xhtml" "index.htm" "index.shtml";
            }

            add_header X-Powered-By PleskLin;

            include "/var/www/vhosts/system/app.mysite.com/conf/vhost_nginx.conf";
    }

    server {
            listen 206.189.5.184:80;

            server_name app.mysite.com;
            server_name www.app.mysite.com;
            server_name ipv4.app.mysite.com;

            client_max_body_size 128m;

            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
```

**//EDIT**

Estos son los permisos de los archivos:

```
drwxrwx--- 15 mysite psacln  4.0K May 25 23:42 .
drwx--x--- 18 mysite psaserv 4.0K May 25 14:51 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 mysite psacln  110K May 25 18:55 abierto.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mysite psacln  2.1K May 25 18:55 app.js
-rw-r--r--  1 mysite psacln  7.5K May 25 18:55 apple-touch-icon2.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mysite psacln  6.8K May 25 18:55 apple-touch-icon.png
drwxr-xr-x 15 mysite psacln  4.0K May 25 19:53 application
-rw-r--r--  1 mysite psacln   62M May 25 18:56 core
drwxrwxr-x  9 mysite psacln  4.0K May 25 23:40 css
-rw-rw-r--  1 mysite psacln   816 May 25 18:55 dot_info.gif
-rw-rw-r--  1 mysite psacln   58K May 25 18:55 error_log
-rw-r--r--  1 mysite psacln     0 May 26 14:36 .htaccess
drwxrwxr-x 34 mysite psacln  4.0K May 25 15:37 img
-rw-rw-r--  1 mysite psacln  6.3K May 25 18:55 index.php
drwxrwxr-x  8 mysite psacln  4.0K May 25 16:01 js
drwxrwxr-x  2 mysite psacln  4.0K May 25 16:04 json
-rw-rw-r--  1 mysite psacln  2.5K May 25 18:55 license.txt
drwxrwxr-x  8 mysite psacln  4.0K May 25 16:04 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--  1 mysite psacln   703 May 25 18:55 npm-debug.log
drwxrwxr-x  8 mysite psacln  4.0K May 25 16:11 pdf
drwxrwxr-x  2 mysite psacln  4.0K May 25 15:20 rrs
-rw-rw-r--  1 mysite psacln   12K May 25 18:55 server.js
-rw-rw-r--  1 mysite psacln   966 May 25 18:55 sitemap.xml
drwxrwxr-x 74 mysite psacln  4.0K May 25 15:24 sound
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysite psacln  4.0K May 25 23:42 src
drwxrwxr-x  8 mysite psacln  4.0K May 25 15:24 system
drwxrwxr-x  2 mysite psacln   16K May 25 15:25 uploads
drwxrwxr-x  3 mysite psacln  4.0K May 25 14:52 .well-known
```

/CSS

```
drwxrwxr-x  9 mysite psacln 4.0K May 25 23:40 .
drwxrwx--- 15 mysite psacln 4.0K May 25 23:42 ..
drwxr-xr-x 15 mysite psacln 4.0K May 25 18:56 admin
drwxrwxr-x  5 mysite psacln 4.0K May 25 15:25 bootstrap
drwxrwxr-x  2 mysite psacln 4.0K May 25 15:25 fullcalendar
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mysite psacln   97 May 25 23:40 .htaccess
drwxrwxr-x  4 mysite psacln 4.0K May 25 18:55 IonIcons
drwxrwxr-x 12 mysite psacln 4.0K May 25 15:25 irakasle
drwxrwxr-x 23 mysite psacln 4.0K May 25 15:26 plataforma
drwxrwxr-x  3 mysite psacln 4.0K May 25 15:26 png
```

**//EDIT**

Si quito de el "additional nginx directives" el código:

```
if (!-f $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php last;
}
```

Me da el error:

```
[Sun May 27 11:36:01.789169 2018] [core:crit] [pid 23845] (13)Permission denied: [client 80.103.137.14:55870] AH00529: /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/app.mysite.com/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/app.mysite.com/' is executable
```

Sino, no me da ningñun error en error_log

Cuando ejecuto "groups mysite"

```
mysite : psacln
```

No puedo añadir las directrices

```
location  /  {
    autoindex  on;
}
```

en additional nginx directives

```
Invalid nginx configuration: nginx: [emerg] duplicate location "/" in /var/www/vhosts/system/app.mysite.com/conf/vhost_nginx.conf:1 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: Has comprovado los permisos que tiene nginx sobre los archivos de la web?

Comment: @LucasD.A.W. he añadido los permisos mas abajo. Si no es eso a lo que te refieres, explícame como comprobar los permisos, por favor. Muchas gracias

Comment: Argoitz: en lugar de marcar como "solucionado", publica tu propia respuesta y acéptala → [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Es un problema de permisos, normalmente me atengo a una `755(o rwxr-xr-x)` en mi raíz web, pero en su caso no creo que sea esto, tiene que seguir éstos pasos:

1. Mire los logs de la web (aquí ya puede encontrar la solución, sino continúe siguiendo los otros pasos) ¿Qué le muestra el log?:

   `/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/logs/error_log`
2. Comprueba que el usuario que tiene acceso a los archivos está en el grupo apache

   `groups user` debería devolverte los grupos a los que está el usuario **user**, entre ellos debería estar apache (`httpd | apache`)
3. Active la [indexación de directorios](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/) para nginx

`location  /  {
  autoindex  on;
}`

4. Si no hay un archivo de índice en el directorio, seguirá recibiendo el mismo error. El archivo de índice más común es index.html. Este valor predeterminado se puede editar en su configuración, usando algo como:

`location / {
    index index.php;
}`

Añade el código en un mismo `location /` si ya tienes uno haz lo siguiente:

```
location  /  {
  index index.php;
  autoindex  on;
  //tu código actual
}
```

Prueba en añadir tu usuario en el grupo apache:

```
sudo adduser mysite apache
```

[Documentación](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001831693-PHP-errors-after-the-migration-Failed-opening-required-Permission-denied)

Comment: He intentado solucionarlo con lo que me has puesto pero no he podido, por las razón que he puesto en el //edit

Comment: @Argoitz intenta hacer los cambios que te he puesto en el edit de la respuesta

Comment: He intentado lo que has puesto no he podido solucionar el problema de 403 forbidden. 
Cuando hago "adduser mysite apache", me dice que no existe el grupo apache.
Estoy utilizando nginx para este subdominio, igual por eso no existe el grupo apache.

Comment: Prueba adduser httpd

Comment: Tampoco existe el grupo httpd (adduser: The group `httpd' does not exist.)

Comment: Que servidor es? Que sistema operativo tiene? Depende del SO será un comando u otro

Comment: Tengo el servidor en digitapocean y es ‪Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS x64‬ y tiene instalado Plesk Onyx 17.8.11. He solucionado el problema actualizando PLESK con las actualizaciones pendientes. Muchas gracuas Lucas por tu ayuda. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Añado la respuesta del OP en modo Wiki de Comunidad, pues [la incluyó en su pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/168187/revisions).</sub>

He realizado la instalación de las actualizaciones que tenía pendientes en PLESK y despues de eso, me he ido a webservices & domains -> Mysite -> Apache & nginx settings y he abilitado el check "Serve static files directly by nginx". 
No se por que de repente funciona ya que este check lo he puesto y quitado varias veces.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]